# Delphi android otimizar carregamento de imagens

Tags: android, delphi, listview, imagem, compressão-de-imagem

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao carregamento de imagens no Delphi.
Minhas imagens possuem em média o tamanho de 47kb, quando exibo elas no
ListView a aplicação chega praticamente a travar pelo o tempo da
resposta.

As imagens estão armazenadas diretamente no banco de dados com o tipo
pré-definido blob.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, a demora do carregamento está relacionado
com a forma como estou trazendo os dados ou é um problema do ListView?

Qual a melhor forma de fazer esse carregamento?
Será que se eu armazenar as imagens em uma pasta no servidor e exibí-las
através da URL eu terei uma melhor performance?

Segue o trecho do código que realizo a leitura e seto ele para o ListView:

```
{$REGION 'Lista Produto'}
      TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
      procedure()
      begin
        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
        procedure()
        begin
          dm.UniQuery1.sql.text := 'SELECT pro_id, pro_ds, pro_img, pro_preco '+
          'FROM produto WHERE '+
          ' pro_ds like '+q('%'+edDescricao.Text+'%')+
          ' AND pro_fabricante_id  like '+q(IfThen((edFabricante.Text<>''),auxFabricante,'%'))+
          ' AND pro_secao  like '+q(IfThen((edSecao.Text<>''),auxSecao,'%'))+
          ' AND pro_merc_id  like '+q(IfThen((edMercado.Text<>''),auxMercado,'%'))+
          ' ORDER BY pro_id DESC';
          dm.UniQuery1.Open;

          try
            ListView1.BeginUpdate;
            ListView1.Items.Clear;

            S := TMemoryStream.Create();

            while not dm.UniQuery1.Eof do
            begin
              LItem := ListView1.Items.add;
              LItem.Text :=  dm.UniQuery1.FieldByName('pro_ds').AsString;
              LItem.Data[TMultiDetailAppearanceNames.Detail1]  :=   dm.UniQuery1.FieldByName('pro_ds').AsString;

              LItem.Data[TMultiDetailAppearanceNames.Detail2]  :=   'R$ '+
                   FormatFloat('###,###0.00', dm.UniQuery1.FieldByName('pro_preco').AsCurrency);

              TblobField(dm.UniQuery1.FieldByName('pro_img')).SaveToStream(S);
              s.Position := 0;
              imgAux.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(S);
              LItem.Bitmap := imgAux.Bitmap;



              dm.UniQuery1.Next;
            end;

            Application.ProcessMessages;
            ListView1.EndUpdate;
          except
            on E: Exception do
              ShowMessage('Erro: ' + E.Message);
          end;

          Application.ProcessMessages;

        end);


        TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
        procedure()
        begin

        end);
      end).Start;
      {$ENDREGION}
```

Comment: É provável que seja a forma de armazenamento, mas podem haver outros problemas, recomendo que poste o código pra podermos detectarmos a falha. Eu não negativei amigo, mas quem negativou foi provavelmente pelo motivo da falta de código na pergunta, o que é totalmente justificavel, então coloque algo para que possamos entender o problema e será bem provavel que removam o downvote :)

Comment: Quantos registros tais trazendo nessa SQL, tente buscar de 50 em 50, trabalhe com cache em memoria com o FireDac, por exemplo, quando for executar esse processo, mostre somente os primeiros 50 ou menos, pois no aplicativo é só uma ferramenta para acesso rápido, então não precisa mostrar muito conteúdo.